# Django & AJAX Changing Div Contents

Tags: python, ajax, django, web-applications

My website have submenus for sections. What I want to do is, when users click the submenu, the content  changes accordingly. For example, if user clicks "Pen", the contents of the  shall be list of pens, clicks "Eraser" , contents shall be eraser list.

How can I achieve this by using Django template and ajax? I know that I could retrieve the information as JSON data and parse it to update the div, but that requires a lot of work and I cannot use the Django template functionality.

I managed to pass the AJAX request to the server and process the list, but how can I return the rendered template as AJAX result?

Comment: Take a look at http://jquery.malsup.com/taconite/. It's a great plugin in that permits complex, multiple-point changes in a single, fire-and-forget call to the server. RTFM for a good time.

Comment: Just return rendered HTML. You don't have to return JSON. And even if you have to, then you can combine JSON with HTML, for example `{ html: somehtml }`. Am I missing something? Not to mention, that there are a lot of cool client-side templating libraries. For example KnockoutJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return the rendered template fragment. You don't need to do anything special. Your Javascript can then just insert it into the DOM at the relevant point.